# Mongoose schema - force one property to be an existing value (enum) of different property on same schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this schema:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  deviceName: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  category: { type: String, enum: DEVICE_CATEGORIES, required: true },
  incompatibleWithDevices: [String]
});

const DeviceModel = model(
  "Device",
  schema
);
```

`incompatibleDevices` should be a list of other devices (by device name) that the device in question cannot work with. So this array should only accept device names that actually exist in the db. For business logic purposes, I can't have a one-to-many relationship here.

I thought about somehow making an enum of all device names that currently exist, but since this is constantly changing as devices get added/removed, I can't think of a way to do this.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this? Perhaps something with a custom validator?

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seams that before creating new `Device` document, you can add validation directly in the backend logic, checking if devices that you are sending exists in the database or not.

You can use `$in` operator for that:

```js
const createDevice = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { deviceName, category, incompatibleWithDevices} = req.body;
 
    const incompatibleDevices = await Devices.find({ deviceName: { $in incompatibleWithDevices }});

    // Here, you do the validation if some deviceName are maybe invalid.
    // At least one device will be invalid if returned array is not the same
    // size as the input array.
    if (incompatibleDevices.length !== incompatibleWithDevices.length) {
      return res.status(400).json({ sucess: false });
    }
 
    // Here you can add the logic that creates the new device since
    // all inputs are valid.
   
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false })
  }
}
```